# golang: export struct slice to excel

Tags: go

What is an idiomatic golang way to dump an array of strucs into an excel file?

an example of my struct:

```
type Item {
    Id                   string `json: "Id"`
    Name                 string `json: "Name"`
    Type                 string `json: "Type"`
}
```

Comment: There is no "idiomatic" way to work with Excel documents. You would have to pick a 3rd party module, review it, and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most "idiomatic" way I can think of in standard Go is using the  `encoding/csv` package to create a CSV file. Excel can load CSVs.

[The package documentation has examples](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv). You'll need to serialize each struct into a `[]string`, and then `encoding/csv` takes it from there.

Alternatively if you want to use 3rd party packages, https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv takes structs and can write those to CSV directly.